Under what conditions on $a$, $\frac12\| x \|^2 + \|x-a\| \geq \frac12\| a \|^2$ holds for all $x$

Under what conditions on $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is the following inequality true for every $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ ? Consider the Euclidean Norm
$$ 
\| x \|^2 /2 + \|x-a\| \geq \| a \|^2 /2 
$$

I was expecting something like $ 0 \leq \|a\| \leq 1$ to be necessary and sufficient, but couldn’t get much around it. Could get some results by plugging specific values of $x$ but I think I'm missing some other important inequality to be used here.

To show that $\Vert a \Vert\leq 1$ is necessary, assume $\Vert a \Vert> 1$ and plug in $x = \frac{a}{\Vert a \Vert}$:
$$
\frac{\Vert x \Vert^2}{2}+\Vert x-a \Vert = \frac{\left\Vert\frac{a}{\Vert a \Vert}\right\Vert^2}{2}+\left\Vert\frac{a}{\Vert a \Vert}-a\right\Vert = \frac{1}{2} + \Vert a \Vert - 1 = \Vert a \Vert - \frac{1}{2}< \frac{\Vert a \Vert^2}{2},
$$
where the last inequality follows from
$$
\frac{1}{2}\left(\Vert a \Vert-1\right)^2 > 0.
$$
Now we show that $\Vert a \Vert\leq 1$ is sufficient: For $a, x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ consider the sphere of radius $\Vert x \Vert$ centered at the origin, then the closest point to $a$ on that sphere is on the straight line through $a$ and the origin, so there is a $t \in \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$
\Vert x \Vert = \Vert ta \Vert
$$
and
$$
\Vert x-a \Vert \geq \Vert ta-a \Vert,
$$
giving us
\begin{align}
\frac{\Vert x \Vert^2}{2}+\Vert x-a \Vert &\geq \frac{\Vert ta \Vert^2}{2}+\Vert ta-a \Vert\\ 
&= \frac{\Vert a \Vert^2 t^2}{2}+\Vert a \Vert|t-1|\\
&\geq \Vert a \Vert^2\left(\frac{t^2}{2}+|t-1|\right)\\
&\geq \frac{\Vert a \Vert^2}{2},
\end{align}
where the last inequality can be obtained by considering the cases $ t \geq 1 $ and $t < 1$ separately.

Letting $x = \frac{a}{1 + t}$ ($t > 0$), we have
$$\frac{1}{2(1 + t)^2}\|a\|^2 + \frac{t}{1 + t}\|a\| \ge \frac12 \|a\|^2$$
or
$$\|a\| \left(\frac{2 + 2t}{t + 2} - \|a\|\right)\ge 0$$
which results in
$$\|a\| \le 1 + \frac{t}{t + 2}.\tag{1}$$
Since (1) holds for all $t > 0$,
we have $\|a\| \le 1$.
On the other hand, if $\|a\|\le 1$, we have
\begin{align*}
 \frac12\|x\|^2 + \|x-a\| - \frac12\|a\|^2
 &= \frac12 \|x - a\|^2 + a^\top (x - a) + \|x-a\|\\
 &\ge -\|a\|\cdot \|x - a\| + \|x - a\|\\
 &\ge 0
\end{align*}
where we use Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz inequality to
obtain $|a^\top(x - a)| \le \|a\|\cdot \|x-a\|$.
